# Validation failed with an "invalid query locator" error

Tags: apex

I was migrating an Apex class from Sandbox to Production system. When validation was ran, it failed with an "invalid query locator" error.
I checked the source code of this part, finding that the sub query for "ActivityHistory" could probably be the root cause of the problem:

```
global void execute( Database.Batchablecontext bc, List<sObject> scope){
    List<Opportunity> opportunityUpdateList = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, List<ActivityHistory>> activityHistMap = new Map<Id, List<ActivityHistory>>();

    for ( sObject s : scope ){
        Opportunity o = (Opportunity)s;
        List<ActivityHistory> actHist = new List<ActivityHistory>();
        for ( ActivityHistory h : o.ActivityHistories ){
            actHist.add (h);
        }
        activityHistMap.put( o.Id, actHist );
    }

......

}
```

I browsed for this error in StackExchange, there is another case with the same problem. It seems the record number is too large and that causes time out or query "release" issue. But I couldn't figure out how I should revise the code. Could anyone be helpful, please? Many thanks!

Comment: While @BorisBachovski has the correct answer for your code when run against live data, getting `Invalid QueryLocator` during the Validation phase of Deployment suggests that the test method(s) are using `SeeAllData=true` or are at V23 or lower.  If you are not mocking Opportunities with Tasks, that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation says:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)

> 1 In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship subqueries, each parent-child relationship counts as an extra query. These types of queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level queries. The row counts from these relationship queries contribute to the row counts of the overall code execution. In addition to static SOQL statements, calls to the following methods count against the number of SOQL statements issued in a request.
>
> ```
> Database.countQuery
> Database.getQueryLocator
> Database.query
> ```

Having said that, I would not write nested SOQL queries, especially for objects that potentially hold thousands of records (which is the case in many enterprise orgs).

I would approach this by separating the query on `Tasks` and `Events` (with status Closed) which essentially represent the `ActivityHistory` object:

```
// Opportunity Id and all the related ActivityHistory records to that oppty
Map <Id, List <Task>> opttyIdToTasks = new Map Map <Id, List <Task>> ();

for ( sObject s : scope )
{
    Id opptyId = (Id)s.get('Id');

    if (opttyIdToTasks.get(opptyId) == null)
    {
        opttyIdToTasks.put(opptyId, new List <Task> ());
    }
}

for (Task taskRecord : [SELECT Id, WhatId, TheRestOfYourFields FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :opttyIdToTasks.keySet() AND Status = 'Closed'])
{
    opttyIdToTasks.get(taskRecord.WhatId).add(taskRecord);
}

// Same thing with Events
```

Comment: Hi Bachovski, thank you very much. Your code inspires me and I will try it in my code.

Comment: Hi, Bachovski, I found the object "ActivityHistories" can't be called in SOQL like this: [SELECT Id, ParentId, TheRestOfYourFields FROM ActivityHistories WHERE ParentId IN :opttyIdToActivityHistory.keySet()]. "ActivityHistories" is not supported. Does it have to be nested in its parent object "Opportunity"?

Comment: ActivityHistories is the child relationship name. When you query the actual object it needs to be its name - `ActivityHistory`. Also `TheRestOfYourFields` is there as a placeholder that I put for you to replace with your own fields that you want to query.

Comment: I gave it a shot as you suggested, an error occurred: Compile Error: entity type ActivityHistory does not support query...... Sounds like ActivityHistory could not be queried directly.

Comment: Oh you're right, I completely forgot that this object must be queried in a nested SOQL. That means that you must limit your number of activity history records, so in your sub-query on `ActivityHistories` try add this : `ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC LIMIT 500`. See if that resolves the issue

Comment: Yes, I think it could be solved by adjusting the number of sub query record, but are there any ways to cover all the records?

Comment: Looking at the problem it turns out the activity history lists nothing more but tasks or events that are closed. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you Bachovski. That's a great idea. Let me try it.